# Connecting mariaDB on Digital Ocean using R Studio

Tags: sql, r, database, mariadb, odbc

I installed mariaDB on digital ocean. I set up user name and password. Now, I am trying to connect it through R studio. But, it is not working.
Code I used.

```
library(odbc)
library("RMariaDB")
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), 
                 Driver = "MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver", 
                 Server = "206.189.---.", #droplet IP
                 Database = "test",
                 Username = "root",
                 Password = " ****" 
                 Trusted_Connection = "True")
```

Error I got :

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: HY000: [ma-3.1.7]Can't connect to MySQL server on '206.189.---.--' (10061)
```

I installed a connection driver  on my windows before running these codes on R Studio. What am I missing here?